# For-loop crashes with large data set VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to give an indexvalue to each datapoint. It works fine for small datasets, but when my dataset is 750,000 the program crashes. Excel gives the following error message: Method value of object range failed.

Here is some of my code:

```
Set datatable = sDataImport.ListObjects("dataTable")  
Dim lastRow As Single
```

'Give an index value to the imported data

```
lastRow = sDataImport.ListObjects("dataTable").ListRows.Count

For i = 1 To lastRow    
datatable.ListColumns("index").DataBodyRange(i, 1).value = i     
Next i
```

Do you guys have any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's solved. Works much quicker aswell.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Application.EnableEvents = False  
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim arr As Variant

ReDim arr(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1) As Variant

For i = 1 To lastRow
    arr(i, 1) = i
Next

datatable.ListColumns("index").DataBodyRange.value = arr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a 2D variant array with index fields like so (for your 75000 row sample):

```
X = Evaluate("=ROW(A1:A75000)")
```